# JSF: Como referenciar Managed Beans

Tags: java, jsf-2.2

Estou começando a estudar JSF e logo já me veio a dúvida de como referenciar a View (JSF) com o Managed Beans. Pois nos exemplos que vejo não consigo perceber como o JSF consegue enxergar o Bean. Por exemplo:

Arquivo.xhtml:

```
...
<p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
<p:inputText id="nome" required="true" value="#{perfilUsuarioBean.nome}"/>
...
```

ArquivoBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean
public class PerfilUsuarioBean {
    ...
    private String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }        
    ...
}
```

Como o JSF consegue enxergar os métodos do Bean?

Answer (score 3):

Repare que nesse exemplo o nome do Bean é `PerfilUsuarioBean`, a view consegue enxergar o Bean pelo nome do mesmo só que sem [CamelCase](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

No seu caso você consegue fazer o binding do input com o Bean da seguinte forma:

```
value="#{perfilUsuarioBean.nome}"
```

Dentro do value usamos EL Expression (Expression Language) que são esse conjunto de símbolos `#{}`, dentro você passa o nome do seu Bean e o valor que quer fazer a ligação (binding).

OBS: Você pode alterar o nome do seu ManegedBean dentro da anotação `@ManagedBean`:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "meuBean")
```

Comment: Valeu Diego, disso eu entendi. Não estou conseguindo é ter acesso ao Bean. Tentei fazer <h:outputText value="#{pesquisaProdutos.ola}" />, porém ele não retorna a String. O que eu acho estranho é que não tem que especificar aonde se encontra o Bean.

Comment: @Raphael , para o JSF conseguir encontrar a variável `ola` no seu ManagedBean, é necessário que o ManagedBean tenha o `getter` da variável `ola`. Ex: `public String getOla() { return this.ola; }`

Comment: @igorventurelli Tentei dessa forma, mas sem sucesso :( O bean que criei está no pacote com.empresa.projeto.controller o JSF vai conseguir achá-lo sozinho?

Comment: @Raphael você atribuiu um valor para a variável `ola`? Se você fizer `public String getOla() { return "Ola Mundo"; }` funciona?

Comment: @igorventurelli Sim, fiz dessa forma e não deu certo. Também inicializei a variável no construtor e não foi.